# ThreeJS: Screen position to camera position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've seen a lot of posts people want to have the camera position to screen position. My question is how to do the contrary.

What I currently want to achieve is set the "door" position to a % of the screen, this calculation is ready, and I do have the final screen X, Y (px) position. The current Z offset = 250 of the camera.

I've found this code to convert camera position to screen position:

```
var vector = projector.projectVector(door.position.clone(), camera);
vector.x = (vector.x + 1) / 2 * window.innerWidth;
vector.y = -(vector.y - 1) / 2 * window.innerHeight;
```

To do the reversie I tried this, but does not give the result I expect:

```
var mouseX = ((perc.x) / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
    mouseY = -((perc.y) / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 1);
projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
return vector.sub(camera.position).normalize()
```

I have tried several ways and tried to Google, but didn't found an answer.

Q: How to convert screen position to camera position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as posted by Gero3, what you want to do is to create a plane that will cover all of your visible camera area (something like `new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5000,5000);` and then use raycaster to locate screen coordinated on that plane.

Here is an example from [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042046/three-js-how-to-get-accurate-world-coordinates-when-renderer-is-in-a-div-and-not/18042975#18042975):

http://jsfiddle.net/PwWbT/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use a large invisble plane that defines in which direction the door can expand and then use a raycaster on the plane to search for the position to where the door object should extend.

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, could you please post an example?